# Glossary terms not aligned vertically

Tags: vertical-alignment, glossaries

I [had a problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21666/glossary-term-list-width) trying to set the width of a glossary column. The suggested solution solved the issue, but raised another problem where the terms are appearing weird, not aligned vertically in the glossary.
A minimum working example is:

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage[nomain,acronym]{glossaries}    
\newcommand{\acronentry}[2]{%
  \newglossaryentry{acro#1}{type=\acronymtype, name={#1},description={#2}, first={#2 (#1)}}%
  \glsadd{acro#1}%
}    
\makeglossaries

\newglossarystyle{clong}{%
 \renewenvironment{theglossary}%
     {\begin{longtable}{p{.3\linewidth}p{\glsdescwidth}}}%
     {\end{longtable}}%
  \renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{}%
  \renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{}%
  \renewcommand*{\glossaryentryfield}[5]{%
    \glstarget{##1}{##2} & ##3\glspostdescription\space ##5\\}%
  \renewcommand*{\glossarysubentryfield}[6]{%
     & \glstarget{##2}{\strut}##4\glspostdescription\space ##6\\}%
  %\renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{ & \\}%
}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\acronentry{ABC}{An example one}
\acronentry{BCD}{A second example}
\acronentry{DEF}{A new third example, with more text}
\begin{document}
\glsaddall
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,style=clong]    
\end{document}
```

What produces:

[image: Resulting document]

How can I make the term and its descriptions aligned to the top vertically keeping the solution provided by @Martin H, as I need that else my layout will break?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Uncomment the redefinition of `\glsgroupskip`; note that the `&` inside it is useless.

Comment: Thanks, that solved the issue! I copied the solution from @Martin H and I will ask him to fix it in its answers to the other question.