# glossary with undesired space

Tags: glossaries

i'm currently writing my thesis, i used the glossary package for my acronyms list, but i dont get the result that i want, i have space between each acronym which i dont want it , i'm newbie in this package and have limited knowledge in it , could you plese help me to reduce the space . This my latex  code that i used :

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
 \usepackage[savewrites,nopostdot,toc,acronym,symbols]{glossaries}
\usepackage{glossary-mcols}
\usepackage{glossary-longragged}


\newacronym{CICS}{CICS}{Customer Information Control System}
\newacronym{EHDM}{EHDM}{Enhanced Hierarchical Development Methodology}
\newacronym{ASF}{ASF}{Algebraic Specification Formalism}
\newacronym{ProCos}{ProCos}{Provably Correct Systems}
\newacronym{HOL}{HOL}{Higher Order Logic}
\newacronym{LOTOS}{LOTOS}{Language Of Temporal Ordering Specification}
\newacronym{CCS}{CCS}{Calculus of Communicating Systems}
\newacronym{CSP}{CSP}{Communicating Sequential Processes}
\newacronym{RAISE}{RAISE}{Rigorous Approach to Industrial Software Engineering}
\newacronym{VDM}{VDM}{Vienna Development Method }
\makeglossaries
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Sample}
This is a sample document that uses the dummy glossary entries
 supplied with the glossaries bundle for testing.
\gls{ASF} \gls{CICS}
 Here are all the entries (including acronyms):

\gls{ASF} \gls{CICS} \gls{CSP} \gls{ProCos}
\gls{VDM} \gls{RAISE} \gls{CCS} \gls{ASF}
\gls{HOL} \gls{EHDM}
 \printglossary[type=acronym,style=super]

 \end{document}
```

and my output result

[image]

Could you please help me ?

Comment: The vertical spaces originate from the style you selected. Take a look at this link http://www.dickimaw-books.com/gallery/glossaries-styles/

Comment: You can add the option `nogroupskip` to the `\usepackage{glossaries}` line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Piet van Oostrum commented, the solution would be to use `nogroupskip` option in the `\usepackage{glossaries}`.

Here is my MWE

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[savewrites,nopostdot,toc,acronym,symbols,nogroupskip]{glossaries}
%\usepackage{glossary-mcols}
%\usepackage{glossary-longragged}  These are redundant
\makeglossaries % it's better practice to have this before the acronyms and gls definitions

\newacronym{CICS}{CICS}{Customer Information Control System}
\newacronym{EHDM}{EHDM}{Enhanced Hierarchical Development Methodology}
\newacronym{ASF}{ASF}{Algebraic Specification Formalism}
\newacronym{ProCos}{ProCos}{Provably Correct Systems}
\newacronym{HOL}{HOL}{Higher Order Logic}
\newacronym{LOTOS}{LOTOS}{Language Of Temporal Ordering Specification}
\newacronym{CCS}{CCS}{Calculus of Communicating Systems}
\newacronym{CSP}{CSP}{Communicating Sequential Processes}
\newacronym{RAISE}{RAISE}{Rigorous Approach to Industrial Software Engineering}
\newacronym{VDM}{VDM}{Vienna Development Method }

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \chapter{Sample}
    This is a sample document that uses the dummy glossary entries
    supplied with the glossaries bundle for testing.
    \gls{ASF} \gls{CICS}
    Here are all the entries (including acronyms):

    \gls{ASF} \gls{CICS} \gls{CSP} \gls{ProCos}
    \gls{VDM} \gls{RAISE} \gls{CCS} \gls{ASF}
    \gls{HOL} \gls{EHDM}
    \printglossary[type=acronym,style=super]

\end{document}
```

notice I commented out `\usepackage{glossary-mcols}` and `\usepackage{glossary-longragged}`. In addition, I moved `\makeglossaries` to before the acronym (and glossaries) definition

Comment: this solution works perfectly thanks , but i don't have enough space between acronyms and their definitions  , how can I do it ?? @Elad Den

Comment: Usually I would advise you to start a new question about this, as this site is supposed to provide questions and answers to other people who ran into the same type of problem. In this case, however, the question has been asked and also answered. http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/21667/90297 This answer is for the `long` style and not the `super` but I think it should also work in your case. Try to do it, if you do not succeed, start a new question. Good luck !